# how to pass one dimension array from two dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using below code to creating Highcharts series

```
for(var i=0;i&lt;legends.length;i++){
    arrSeries[i]= {
       name:legends[i].replace(/'/g, ""),
       data: dataSeries[i]
    }
}
```

In this data series is a two-dimensional array. and arrSeries is the series array which I pass to highchart series. When I debug the code and analyze arrSereies then it shows values like below

```
[Object{name="dilip",data=[1440]}]
```

in this, the name part is correct and the graph is plotting the legend properly but datapart which is showing 1440, but this 1440 is actually the length of elements in one dimensional array while it should show the elements within an array. Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: What does `dataSeries` look like? What're you expecting as the value for property _data_?

Comment: Is hard to tell when we don't know how is your `dataSeries` array. Before the `for` block, use `console.log(dataSeries)` and post it.

Comment: in firebug, dataSeries looks as  below
[[0, null, null, 1437 more...]]

Comment: May i know your `dataSeries.length` value ?

Comment: dataSeries.length values is 1

Comment: So, your data isn't two dimensional. There's only one array inside.